# Aggregate works in command line but not with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to find out why an aggregate command works in mongoDB but not in mongoose:

```
db.providers.aggregate({$geoNear{near[-117.67625427246094,33.58256912231445],
distanceField: "dist", 
spherical: true, maxDistance: 71591.87002706563, query{type_id:1}}}).pretty();
```

The following returns a single row:

```
"provider_id" : 1366826512,
"providername" : "Dover XXXX",
"loc" : {
    "type" : "Point",
    "coordinates" : [
        -117.9081489,
        33.6195128
    ]
},
"dist" : 0.003432172265332921
```

But the same command does not return anything with mongoose.

```
Provider.aggregate([
        { 
            $geoNear: { 
                near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [parseFloat(pLatLngArray[0]), parseFloat(pLatLngArray[1])] }, 
                distanceField: "dist",
                spherical: true, 
                //distanceMultiplier: 3963.2,
                maxDistance: parseFloat(pRadius),
                query: { type_id: pType },
            } 
        }
        ],
        function(err, result){              
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR: ProviderModel::listProviders: ", err);
            return callback([]);
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));        


        return callback(result);
    });
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any field called `pType` in your data, and if you got that data from something like a `req` object, then it's probably a "string" and not numeric like it is in your original query. Also the order of coordinates is "longitude,latitude" and you have the parameters reversed in the naming of `pLatLongArray`. That leads me to think you possibly have the values reversed. Google maps API for example returns in the reverse order to the GeoJSON format order used by MongoDB.

Comment: Also note that your first query is "different" in that you supplied a "legacy coordinate pair" as opposed to the second attempt where you use a GeoJSON format. The `"dist"` field returned will therefore have a different value, and be in "meters" as opposed to the first query output which is in "radians".

Comment: Well it was the pType, just as you had stated. Changing it to Number(pType) resolved the issue. BTW, I just named lat and lng wrong, otherwise the order is correct. Thanks a whole bunch for the tip.